# Question is related to TKINTER function return value

Tags: tkinter

On clicking a button in tkinter a function return a value. How to access this value so that i can use it my code.Please help

It retuurn value when i call the function but i want to access the function value after clicking button work on ghat function

Comment: Please also look at [event driven programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming)

Answer (score 0):

> On clicking a button in tkinter a function return a value. How to access this value so that i can use it my code.

The return value of functions called via the `Button` `command` attribute isn't accessible. That is because this command isn't called by your code. Instead, it's called by `mainloop` which simply ignores return values.

You must either set a global variable or an instance variable that other code can access.